# Why is this change causing seg fault?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following method:

```
 17 //returns size in bytes of binary file stream
 18 //leaves the file at original position
 19 long getFileSize(FILE * fp)
 20 {
 21    long pos = -1;
 22    fpos_t *curPos;
 23    if(fgetpos(fp, curPos) == 0)
 24    {
 25       fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
 26       pos = ftell(fp);
 27       fsetpos(fp, curPos);
 28    }
 29
 30    return pos;
 31 }
```

This will compile and work but compiler will give me a warning because curPos is not a initialized variable.

If I change that line to (which the compiler recommends)

```
 22    fpos_t *curPos = NULL;
```

I receive a seg fault.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Before you explicitly told curPos to point nowhere, it pointed to some random location, which just happened to be valid writable memory, and so the program worked by coincidence. To have it work by actually being right, you'll have to actually allocate some memory for it to point to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't allocated `curPos`.
So either allocate it on the heap (and be sure to free it later!)

```
fpos_t *curPos = malloc(sizeof(fpos_t));
```

Or on the stack

```
fpos_t curPos;
```

In case you allocate it on the stack you need to pass the reference to `fgetpos`:

```
fgetpos(fp, &curPos)
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared `curPos` as a pointer (`fpos_t *`), but never filled in the address where the data is to be found.  That is why you get a segmentation fault when you try to store a value in the location indicated by the address (when you changed it to `fpos_t *curPos = NULL;`)

As I look at the signature for `fgetpos()`, I realize that what you want is to declare an `fpos_t` and pass the address of the storage you have allocated so that `fgetpos()` will write the value.

```
fpos_t curPos;
fgetpos(fp, &curPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

`curPos` needs to point to a `fpos_t` object, so `fgetpos` has a place to store the position.